# .gradle folder is red after android studio update, how to fix?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just updated my Android Studio to **3.0.1** which also asked me to update gradle for the project. So, after update ".gradle" folder is now marked red and project structure is also not in well manner. App is building fine and produce no errors but I wonder why this happened and how to fix it?

Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug it's a feature. If the folder had an error it would have red underlining underneath the folder name and the code would mark the errors as well. It is a typical structure of the project in the `Project` view and brown folders mean ignored folders (folders that are not related to your project but are generated from compilation). You have the choice of several other views such `Android` which hides all the ignored folders for you and you get it by clicking on the `Project` drop-down above the folders and choosing `Android`. If that doesn't meet your needs, then you could customize the IDE in the settings although there isn't much on controlling such things.